# Creating backup of my .mdf DB file during runtime

Tags: c#-4.0

when i try to use this code for creating backup of my DB this error occures ?

```
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        File.Copy(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB.mdf", dlg.FileName );
```

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB.mdf' because it is being used by another process.